# Bypass navigator custom shell and go into winCE

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, windows-embedded

I have Shtrumann Link 500sl navigator powered by winCE 6.0. I want to get into windows shell (or explorer or something). I know it’s possible as I did it three of four years ago, but I can’t recall exactly how. All I remember is that the method involved usage of SD card with especially formatted text file. The text file contained path to shell.exe (or something alike). I can’t remember exact file names. For some reason google didn’t help.I’d appreciate any ideas (including proper search terms for google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recovered my old solution. I did it as follows:
1. On SD card, create ascii file called shell.ini. This file consists of a single line '\windows\explorer.exe' (without quotation marks)
2. Insert the SD and reboot
3. Navigator boots into its regular shell, if you chose 'navigate' from the menu it takes you to winCE explorer